# streaming live video to a view

Tags: android

I need to stream live video from an IP camera to a view.  There are apps that do this, to be sure, but I need to do it in my own app.

There are simple examples on the web of doing this with VideoView and with MediaPlayer, but these don't work, at least with the Panasonic camera I'm working with.  Running in the emulator, I can see that Android sends an RTSP DESCRIBE request to the camera, receives a response, and then simply stops.  VNC continues with SETUP and PLAY requests.

It would be easy enough to solve this problem if I had a way of controlling the rtsp dialog, but I can't see any way to get to that low a level with ViedoView or MediaPlayer.  Is there a way to do it?

Thanks.